# Javascript popup window doesn't re-open on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

The following javascript code opens a popup window if it's not already open. This works fine on my development PC local and online. 
However, testing on 3 different mobiles, the popup window is opened only the first time.
Once closed, my script is unable to re-open the popup.

I suppose, for some reason ldlWobjRef_1 is not reset to null, but I cannot figure out why the problem appears only on mobiles.

```
  var ldlWobjRef_1 = null; // global variable popup activ

  function open_win() {
      if (ldlWobjRef_1 == null || ldlWobjRef_1.closed) { // if no popup

            ldlWobjRef_1 = window.open ("jplayer/popup.html", "myWindow", "height=418, width=455, left=500, top=250, toolbar=0, titlebar=0, menubar=0, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no,  status=no");
       }
      else {    

            ldlWobjRef_1.focus();   
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this within a div just like so.

```
<div  onclick='window.open ("jplayer/popup.html", "myWindow", "height=418, width=455, left=500, top=250, toolbar=0, titlebar=0, menubar=0, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no,  status=no");'> </div>
```

Comment: Just tested and it works in all major browsers and on mobiles.Thank you very much. Could you please explain why our script approach didn't work?